# custom ASP.NET template control without placeholder tags

Tags: asp.net, templates, custom-controls

Let's say I have a custom template control, that can be used in pages like so:

```
<AR:CustomControl runat="server">
    <ViewTemplate>
        <span>stuff</span>
    </ViewTemplate>
</AR:ModalLink>
```

Since there is only one template field, the  element isn't really necessary.  Is there a way I can edit my control so it can be used like?

```
<AR:CustomControl runat="server">
    <span>stuff</span>
</AR:ModalLink>
```

Note that this is a UserControl with an ASCX file.  So I don't think I can simple inherit from an existing control like Label.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution here:
"http://alvinzc.blogspot.com/2006/10/aspnet-basic-of-custom-server-control_25.html"

In a nutshell:

```
[ParseChildren(true, "Content")]
[PersistChildren(false)]
public partial class CustomControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    ...

    [Browsable(false),
    PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerDefaultProperty),
    TemplateContainer(typeof(Contents)),
    TemplateInstance(TemplateInstance.Single)]
    public ITemplate Content { ... }
}
```

Comment: Link should be http://alvinzc.blogspot.com/2006/10/aspnet-basic-of-custom-server-control_25.html